# how do i access id tags and other element values for an element that is saved as a string in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

i want to use document.querySelector("#") on an input element (and check if it is chekced of) that is saved in a string, and then retrieved by innerHTML. however i cant figure out how to get acesess to it?

i want to run through the array, and be able to log when the radio button is checked off. to do so, i have tried using queryselectorAll("radio") an array with querySelector and the different ids for the different radio button, but i dosent seem to work

```
 <body>

<div class="stemmegiving"> </div>

<script>
var stemmegivingEl= document.querySelector(".stemmegiving")

    var alt=['<input type="radio" name="stem" class="kanpper" checked id=" Rødt" >',
    '<input type="radio" name="stem" value=""class="kanpper"id="SP"> ',
    '<input type="radio" name="stem" value=""class="kanpper"id="AP"> ']

for (var i = 0; i < alt.length; i++) {
  stemmegivingEl.innerHTML+= alt[i]
}

  var giStemmeEl = document.querySelector("#giStemme")
var alt2=[document.querySelector("#rødt"), document.querySelector("#SV"),document.querySelector("#AP")]

  for (var i = 0; i < alt.length; i++) {
    if (alt2[i].checked) {
      console.log(alt2[i] + " is true");
      console.log(typeof alt2[i]);
    }
    else {
       console.log(i + "not true");
   console.log(typeof alt2[i]);
 }
  }

  </script>
  </body>
```

i would like to be able to access it the same way as if you
make an input element in body and then querySelect it

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery, you can parse html on the fly and then you'd have that query selector functionality you want.

```
$(alt[i]).prop('checked');
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/